# How to change font size and type of chemnum labels?

Tags: chemnum

I currently find the autolabels from `chemnum` package to be too big and ugly. I'd like to change their font size and type, how can I do this?
Download the .eps for the MWE [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q3n87tv07tvzsfo/myfigure.eps?dl=0).

[image: How to change the font type and size under the molecules?]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\Molar}{\textsc{m}}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{chemscheme}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{color}

 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,}

\begin{document}
\title{XYZ}
\author{\small{One and Two}}
\date{\small{30\textsuperscript{th} May, 2018}}


\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
      ...
    \end{abstract}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\replacecmpd{1} 
\replacecmpd{2}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{my figure}
\caption{Caption Here}
\label{myfigure}
\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{rsc}
\bibliography{REF.bib}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: `\small` doesn't take an argument and you are loading `hyperref` too early.

Comment: @cfr when should I load hyperref and what is the issue with where it is now?

Comment: Load it last, with a few exceptions (e.g. `cleveref` must be load afterwards). It adapts to what is loaded, so it won't work properly where it is now.

Comment: @cfr it works perfectly fine where it is right now in my main document. But I'll do as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `chemnum`'s option `replace-style`:

```
\setchemnum{replace-style=\small}
```

The default setting of the package is

```
\setchemnum{replace-style=\sffamily}
```

With your example this gives:

[image]